# spring-boot cannot start in docker

Tags: java, spring, shell, docker, spring-boot

I've a little problem with run my spring boot application in docker.

stack: maven 3+, spring boot(jpa/rest/jetty) - mysql - deploy in docker

So, i've have in my pom file

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.M3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- SPRING BOOT DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <!-- add for exlude tomcat -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END SPRING BOOT DEPENDENCIES-->
    <!-- Jetty (tomcat replacement) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- mysql connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- optional dependency javax.el -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- google http client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.21.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- google http jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
        <version>1.21.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Environment:
Ubuntu 16.04 x64
The problem:
Locally: I try to run my app with follow command in terminal

```
user$ java -Xmx768m -jar /mnf-backend.jar --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR/app_1?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
user$ #<--- LOOK AT THIS jvm has return of control with 1 status (or same status but not negative)
 :: Spring Boot ::             (v1.4.0.M3) # <--- spring boot starts by itself. HOW????
```

it's not good by i can tolerate it. But not docker.
When commands above will be run in docker then docker stop container (because -> app exit with status 1)

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Xmx768m", "-jar", "/mnf-backend.jar", "--spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR/app_1?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false"]
```

Docker will start container 1 second and immediately stop container because java return control.
I look for method which allow me to configure spring app for predictable behavior or any ideas how to improve my docker instructions.
my dockerfile content:

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim

ENV MNFB_ENV production
ENV SERVER_PORT 9000

ADD ./builds/mnf-latest.jar mnf-backend.jar

EXPOSE 9000



ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Xmx768m", "-jar", "/mnf-backend.jar", "--spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR/minifinance?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false"]
```

docker logs of a container
[image]

For example: when i've start nodejs app control not return until application not finished

```
user$ node ./server.js
[...here program output and stdout strings]
[... it may be stopped by ctrl+c for example]
```

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile you used? And, what is not good that you can tolerate?

Comment: sorry for my English. I mean i can tolerate this spring behavior locally but not in docker

Comment: if the app (java) exits with the error code 1 - that means you have some problems in the environment, not Spring Boot. Look up the docker container ID or name, and use `docker logs <container-id>` to figure out what went wrong there.

Comment: Did you get any error message before the container stopped? If not, can you post the `docker logs <container-id>` output?

Comment: Logs are missing :( No any strings into logs output. See screenshot above

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the problem is the ampersand (&) in your command line:

`--spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR/app_1?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false"]`

Try to escape it:

`--spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR/app_1?autoReconnect=true\&useSSL=false"]`

The ampersand denotes the shell to start your process in the background. That's exactly what's happening on your local machine. If you start your jar, the process should start in foreground... and the prompt shouldn't return directly.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple and clean, we have added database properties in the database.properties

## mongo db database configuration

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=abc-auth
spring.data.mongodb.host=192.168.2.2
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.password=abc234quth
spring.data.mongodb.username=abc-auth
```

We push this file while running the Docker, so only database properties will get override with the existing application.properties

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/home/docker/service/abc.jar","--spring.config.location=application.properties"]
```